# HSQL SELECT Statement Not working

Tags: hsqldb

I am new in HSQL. Tried a Procedure like below;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetData(ObjectId VARCHAR(36)) READS SQL DATA 
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
BEGIN ATOMIC
    DECLARE MaxVal NUMERIC(19,2);
    DECLARE MinVal NUMERIC(19,2);
    DECLARE BiggestObjectName VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE SmallestObjectName VARCHAR(50);

    SET MaxVal = (SELECT MAX(HeightValue) FROM ObjectData WHERE ObjectId=ObjectId);
    SET MinVal = (SELECT MIN(HeightValue) FROM ObjectData WHERE ObjectId=ObjectId);
    SET BiggestObjectName = (SELECT ObjectName FROM ObjectData WHERE ObjectId=ObjectId AND HeightValue=MaxVal);
    SET SmallestObjectName = (SELECT ObjectName FROM ObjectData WHERE ObjectId=ObjectId AND HeightValue=MinVal);

  if MaxVal IS NOT NULL THEN
    DECLARE result CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
        SELECT MaxVal AS MaximumHeight, MinVal AS MinimumHeight, BiggestObjectName AS LargestDisplayCaseName, SmallestObjectName AS SmallestDisplayCaseName FOR READ ONLY;
  OPEN result;
END
```

But i get error;

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: ; required: INTO
```

Is it not the correct syntax?

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your stored procedure. For one I don't think you can `declare` a cursor as part of an `IF` statement.

Assignment of a variable needs to be either using `select ... into` or you need to put the select statement between parentheses:

```
SET MaxVal = (SELECT MAX(HeightValue) FROM ObjectData WHERE ObjectId=ObjectId);
SET ObjectName = (SELECT ObjectName FROM ObjectData WHERE ObjectId=ObjectId AND HeightValue=MaxVal);
```

or

```
SELECT MAX(HeightValue) 
  into maxval
FROM ObjectData 
WHERE ObjectId=ObjectId;
```

You also can't use `=` or `<>` to compare `NULL` values. `if MaxVal != NULL THEN` needs to be

```
if maxval is not null then 
   ...
end if; --<< you also forgot the `end if`
```

You also can't use a `SELECT` statement without a `FROM` clause, and I don't think you can define a cursor that only selects values from variables in HSQLDB.

But don't need the intermediate selects anyway, you can do that in a single select:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetData(ObjectId VARCHAR(36)) READS SQL DATA 
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
BEGIN ATOMIC

  DECLARE result CURSOR FOR
    select o1.heightvalue as maximumheight, o1.objectname as displaycasename
    from objectdata o1
    where objectid = 'one' 
    and heightvalue = (select max(heightvalue) 
                       from objectdata o2 
                       where o2.objectid = o1.objectid);

  OPEN result;

END;
```

Comment: What if i need to calculate a `MIN` value with `MAX` value for bigest and smallest objects. Can i do it in a single query? Question Modified to better describe what i mean

Comment: @Rajkishan: you know turned a question about the syntax of stored procedures into something different. It's now about finding [tag:greatest-n-per-group] efficiently. This is being asked several times a day, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+sql

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the correct syntax to create the procedure. According to the syntax you have to put the value(s) selected from table into a local variable(s). Follow the following example.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_customer(IN id INT, OUT firstname VARCHAR(50), OUT lastname VARCHAR(50)) 
    READS SQL DATA
    BEGIN ATOMIC
    -- this statement uses the id to get firstname and lastname
    SELECT first_name, last_name INTO firstname, lastname FROM customers WHERE cust_id = id;
END
```

I hope it'll help you.

Comment: But it is increasing the number of parameters. And i cannot do that. I am writing this for a test. Is there no other way?